# How to use Pandas (Python) to report user-item interactions

Tags: python, pandas

I have some server log data, showing user and item interactions. I am not interested in knowing how many times a user looked at an item, only that it happened. Is there a way in Pandas to aggregate both columns at once to accomplish this without a loop?

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame([['A', 2], ['A', 2], ['A', 3], ['B', 1], ['B', 1], ['B', 1], ['B', 3]], columns=['UserID', 'ItemID'])

print a
# Desired output:
print pd.DataFrame([['A', 2], ['A', 3], ['B', 1], ['B', 3]], columns=['UserID', 'ItemID'])
```

### INPUT:

```
    UserID  ItemID
0      A       2
1      A       2
2      A       3
3      B       1
4      B       1
5      B       1
6      B       3
```

### DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
  UserID  ItemID
0      A       2
1      A       3
2      B       1
3      B       3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> a
  UserID  ItemID
0      A       2
1      A       2
2      A       3
3      B       1
4      B       1
5      B       1
6      B       3
>>> a.drop_duplicates()
  UserID  ItemID
0      A       2
2      A       3
3      B       1
6      B       3
>>> a.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
  UserID  ItemID
0      A       2
1      A       3
2      B       1
3      B       3
```

Comment: DSM - simple, great solution. Thank you.